# Cannot perform reduce with flexible type error in Sankey HoloViews

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sankey-diagram, holoviews

I have this code but i keep getting a "cannot reduce with flexible type error"

```
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
from holoviews import opts, dim
hv.extension('bokeh')
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
    

file input path
csv_path = r'C:\Users\jose\Downloads\enron-v1.csv'
df_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_path ,index_col=0)

#filtering a new dataframe
df_filter = df_csv[["fromJobtitle", "toJobtitle"]]
df_final = df_filter.groupby(df_filter.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()

#creating a co-occurence dataframe to show relationships
df_final['combination'] = df_final.apply(lambda row: tuple(sorted([row['fromJobtitle'],  
row['toJobtitle']])), axis=1)
df_final = df_final.groupby('combination').sum().reset_index()
df_final['from'] = df_final.apply(lambda row: row['combination'][0], axis=1)
df_final['to'] = df_final.apply(lambda row: row['combination'][1], axis=1)
df_final = df_final.drop('combination', axis=1)
 
#turning final dataframe to a list
df_sankey = df_final.to_numpy().tolist()


sankey = hv.Sankey([df_sankey])
sankey.opts(width=600, height=400)
renderer.save(sankey, 'h2')
```

error message given in VScode:

```
File "c:/Users/js/Documents/DBL/sankey.py", line 23, in <module>
    sankey = hv.Sankey([df_sankey])
  File "C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\holoviews\element\sankey.py", line 349, in __init__
    nodes, edgepaths, graph = _layout_sankey.instance().layout(self)
  File "C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\holoviews\element\sankey.py", line 49, in layout
    self.computeNodeValues(graph)
  File "C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\holoviews\element\sankey.py", line 156, in computeNodeValues
    source_val = np.sum([l['value'] for l in node['sourceLinks']])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in sum
  File "C:\Users\jose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2247, in sum
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
  File "C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 87, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I tried copy pasting the actual list (df_sankey) into the hv.sankey([]) and it works, but when i specify the input (df_sankeys) I get this error. Sankeys documentation on Holoviews 1.14 says it is possible to use a pandas dataframe or a list as input, so idk what went wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert but I believe your error is a result of the column order in your df_sankey dataframe.  Reorder your columns to ['from', 'to', 'size'].

```
df_sankey = df_sankey.loc[:, ['from', 'to', 'size']]
```